# Android UI design pattern - Options Menu

Tags: android, oop, android-layout

I want to use my options menu on every activity that I have on my project.

So I've created an OptionsMenuActivity which inherits from Activity.

Each activity I've created inherit from it.

The problem is when creating MyPreferenceActivity which inherits from PreferenceActivity, I cannot use it.

What is the best way doing it ?

Comment: What is the problem when creating MyPreferenceActivity ?

Comment: That I cannot inherit from "OptionsMenuActivity"

Comment: Hum, ok, didn't figure that you wanted your PreferenceActivity to also have access to the common Options... Sorry

Comment: Not sure, but try to create your own application class and put all the option menu stuff there and then you can access that application object anywhere in ur project or app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are looking to do is find a place to put the onCreateOptionsMenu() and onOptionsItemSelected() methods you can create a separate class with those two methods, make an instance of that class a member of all your activities, and make these two methods 'pass through' methods in your activities, deferring to the member object that now handles the requests.

Your new class does not have to inherit from Activity to do its job.  However, the onOptionsItemSelected() method may have to return some indication as to whether it actually handled the request or not so your Activity's method can call 'super.onOptionsItemSelected()' as necessary.